# how to calculate data in a Row using C# with access 2010?

Tags: c#, ms-access, calculator

im trying to calculate electricity consumption using this formula:

electricity consumption = Usage Per Day * Power (Watt) * Number of Item * 30 / 1000

but i have no idea how to call the data in a row from access.

tell me if you need more info.

[image]

i tried using this code but it tells me incorrect format of string input. any idea

try
            {
                OleDbCommand cal = test.CreateCommand();

```
            int q;
            for (q = 0; q <= "ID".Count(); q++)
            {
                int x = 111 + q;

                cal.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Energy_Audit WHERE ID=" + x;
                cal.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cal.ExecuteNonQuery();


                double i = Double.Parse("Usage Per Day") * Double.Parse("Power (Watt)") * Double.Parse("Number of Item") * 30 / 1000;  }
```

Comment: Well if those are column names then you would need to put them in square brackets like `[Usage Per Day] * [Power (Watt)] * [Number of Item] * 30 / 1000`

Comment: emm. i tried it. but can you tell me in more specified? like how to write the command statement?

Comment: i guess you can replace it for the `*` in the query so that i would output you a column of your req consumption values

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem using this code :

```
            OleDbCommand cal = test.CreateCommand();
            int q;
            int count = int.Parse(AppList.Rows.Count.ToString());

            for (q = 0; q < count - 1; q++)
            {
                int x = 111 + q;

                cal.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Energy_Audit WHERE RecordID=" + x;
                cal.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataReader ObjReader = cal.ExecuteReader();

                while (ObjReader.Read())
                {

                    double r = Double.Parse(ObjReader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                    double w = Double.Parse(ObjReader.GetValue(3).ToString());
                    double t = Double.Parse(ObjReader.GetValue(4).ToString());

                    double i = r * w * t * 30 / 1000;

                    ObjReader.Close();
                }
```